# Floating pictures, text and table (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I've checked a couple of different answers here but none have really helped me, so I'm asking specifically for me this time. Hope you understand:). 
I want to make the following layout:

```
text - picture

text - picture

    table
```

Right now, I've managed to get the following layout:

```
table header text - picture

             text - picture
t   a    b      l       e
```

I hope it's understandable. Can't really provide a link to the page because it is uploaded to a teacher's server.

This is the code I've got so far:

HTML for the images (I don't think the table is necessary to include):

```
 <div id="content"> 

            <div class="minahundarimg1">
              <a target="_blank" href="Nino1.jpg">
                <img src="Nino1.jpg" alt="Nino" width="300" height="200" >
              </a>
              <div class="desc">Nino, 2 &aringr </div>
            </div>

            <div class="minahundarimg2">
              <a target="_blank" href="DSC_0015.JPG">
                <img src="DSC_0015.JPG" alt="Marcus" width="300" height="200" >
              </a>
              <div class="desc">Marcus, 4 &aringr </div>
            </div>

            <p>
```

Then CSS for the images:

```
div.minahundarimg1{
     float: right;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div.minahundarimg2 {
     float: right;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
div.desc {
    float: left;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

and CSS for the table (in case it's necessary):

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;

}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

The table is within a div called `<div id="text2">`. This is the CSS to that one.

```
div#text2 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

If anyone can help me solve my problem or point me in the right direction I would be really glad. Also, if there is any problem with my question, please don't hesitate to ask. 
Thank you in advance:).

Comment: Can add a printscreen of what you already did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way? https://jsfiddle.net/atqjbjzk/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    div.minahundarimg1{
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div.minahundarimg2 {
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
div.desc {
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;

}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

div#text2 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="content"> 
    <div class="minahundarimg1">
        <div class="desc">Nino, 2 &aringr </div>
        <a target="_blank" href="Nino1.jpg">
            <img src="Nino1.jpg" alt="Nino" width="300" height="200" >
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="minahundarimg2">
        <div class="desc">Marcus, 4 &aringr </div>
        <a target="_blank" href="DSC_0015.JPG">
            <img src="DSC_0015.JPG" alt="Marcus" width="300" height="200" >
        </a>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped:)!

Answer (score 0):

1. you can apply css class text-center to the div containing the table like

   ....
2. if abouve doesnot work then, try using media query for that div

    `@media(min-width:500px){
    div#text2 {
    margin-left: 30px;
   }
   }`